# Custom keyboard in chat with bot

Tags: telegram-bot

I have a bot. In a chat with a bot, a custom keyboard is used. When I delete only a bot message in a chat, the custom keyboard disappears, does not close, but it disappears. When I delete only my messages in this chat, the keyboard does not disappear. As I know, a custom keyboard should be constant until the bot sends a new custom keyboard. Is this a bug?

Answer (score 0):

Let's look at API for [message](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#message), it says that [inline keyboard](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#inlinekeyboardmarkup) is connected to a "message it belongs to".

This behaviour seems normal, when keyboard disappears when message it belongs to has been deleted.

Comment: Why do you write about the inline keyboard? I did not ask about the inline keyboard.

Comment: The answer would be the same. Both, InlineKeyboardMarkup or ReplyKeyboardMarkup (what you name custom keyboard) belong to reply_markup https://core.telegram.org/bots/api/#replykeyboardmarkup of  the message, that is where your keyboard stored.